# TTS locale ignored

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I can't make TTS Locale to work.

```
  window.TTS.checkLanguage()
```

return me this list 
     `["ku,pt_BR,ta,ja_JP,sk_SK,tr_TR,ru_RU,ko_KR,hi_IN,fil_PH,fi_FI,ca,hr,es_ES,sk,ro_RO,zh_TW,sw,el_GR,fr_BE,en_GB,nl_NL,la,et_EE,pt_PT,fr_FR,bs,km_KH,vi_VN,en_AU,pl_PL,da_DK,sq,cy,en_US,bn_IN,si_LK,in_ID,yue_HK,uk_UA,bn_BD,sr,en_IN,cs_CZ,it_IT,ne_NP,de_DE,es_US,zh_CN,th_TH,sv_SE,nb_NO,hu_HU"`
]

Now, I try to run:

```
window.TTS.speak({
        text: 'hello world!!',
        locale: 'en-GB',
        rate: 1.3
    }, function () {
        // Do Something after success
    }, function (reason) {
        // Handle the error case
    });
```

'en-GB' exist but it read it as EN-US voice.

I'm using tts plugin for cordova(https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-tts) but I think it releated to android TTS. any idea why it's happen?

Answer (score 0):

Install voice data for `en_GB` to your device.

- [Android Accessibility Help](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006983?hl=en)
- [Google's Text-to-speech engine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tts&hl=en)
- [Android Compatibility Definition](https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd#3_11_text-to-speech)

According to [the source code](https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-tts/blob/master/src/android/TTS.java), the plug-in internally calls method [`setLanguage`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setlanguage) in order to choose language and country for voice. The method returns the following supporting status:

- `LANG_AVAILABLE`
- `LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE`
- `LANG_COUNTRY_VAR_AVAILABLE`
- `LANG_MISSING_DATA`
- `LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED`

If your device doesn't have voice data for `en_GB`, the method can set `en_US` as a fallback and return `LANG_AVAILABLE`. In that case, TTS speaks text in `en_US` voice.